# Alternate to class objects in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I have code like

```
class abc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0
        self.c = 0
```

I am making array of objects of this class as below:

```
objs = np.array([ abc() for x in range(10)])
```

Is there any data structure similar to classes which can hold values a,b,c as in class abc. Also I could make array of that data structure as done above in objs object.
Kindly if anyone could guide.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a class?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. What's wrong with the `class`? Perhaps `collections.namedtuple` could help, hard to tell.

Comment: Anyway, a class is not really a data-structure, it is a programming construct that can be used to implement concrete data structures.

Comment: Also, using a numpy array this way sort-of defeats the purpose of numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.3+, you can use [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```
>>> import types
>>> types.SimpleNamespace(a=0, b=0, c=0)
namespace(a=0, b=0, c=0)

>>> obj = types.SimpleNamespace(a=0, b=0, c=0)
>>> obj.a
0
>>> obj.b
0
>>> obj.c
0
```

---

In lower version, use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to make a custom type.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>>
>>> abc = namedtuple('abc', 'a b c')
>>> abc(a=0, b=0, c=0)
abc(a=0, b=0, c=0)
```

But it does not allow attribute setting unlike `types.SimpleNamespace`:

```
>>> obj = abc(a=0, b=0, c=0)
>>> obj.a
0
>>> obj.a = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: But I have version 2.7.11. Is there any alternate to classes for this version of python?

Comment: @user271017, I updated the answer to an alternative with a note.